# Combining 3 MySQL queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is take a whole table and find out what the `id` is of the member whose email address is in the value of `emails.from` and put their `id` in there instead. I'm trying to improve my performance by using IDs instead of email addresses but am unable to complete this task.

```
$mysql = new mysql();
$mysql->query('SELECT `from` FROM `emails` ORDER BY `id` ASC' );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql->result)){
    $mysql2 = new mysql();
    $mysql2->query('SELECT `id` FROM `exchange` WHERE `email` = "'.$row['from'].'"');

    $details = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql2->result);


    $mysql2->query('UPDATE `emails` SET `from` = '.$details['id'].' WHERE `from` = "'.$row['from'].'"');
}
```

Comment: you might want to look into using PDO or MySQLi

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem with your database design if you need to do that to join the two tables. Please post your schema so we can see whether that can be done with no changes.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: [This diagram may help you](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code, you could try something like this:

```
UPDATE     `emails`
INNER JOIN `exchange` ON `exchange`.`email` = `emails`.`from`
SET `emails`.`from` = `exchange`.`id`
```

Comment: I would consider it a severe design flaw if he's joining with a text column.

Comment: What im doing is replacing the text column with the id of the user to fix this flaw

Answer (score 2):

No need to look it up if you're doing the whole table.

```
UPDATE emails SET from=id
```

Will do each row in the table.

Comment: how will it get info from both tables?

Answer (score 1):

The query below should do the trick :)

```
update emails 
set `from`=(select e.id from exchange as e where e.email=em.`from`)
from emails as em
order by em.id asc
```